# get gmail user account with GAE/java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, gmail

I want to get the gmail user id with GAE / java.
and tried all the examples, but all return null.

anyone knows how, all I want is to get the ID or username.

that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    String email = user.getEmail();
} else {
    // no user logged in
}
```

Also take a look at the docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers.html

Update:

Of course you need to enable user authenticaiton in your configuration to require users to login and see their data: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication

See this to see how to make your own login: 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html

Comment: only return null, I need to redirect the user to log in with his google account and be redirected again to my app, I have a URL but only returns a token that I really do not know, and can not find how to use it, 

http://www.google.com/a/sanmina-sci.com/AuthSubRequest?scope=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&session=1&secure=0&next=http://www.example.com/welcome.html

Comment: You have to configure your app to require authentication - see updated answer.